# Consolidate data from multiple sheets with multiple rows of headers VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In advance, thank you for all your help.

The task that I have is I need to copy data from two sheets in to "Consolidation" sheet. Both sheets have similar headers, but I only need to keep one set of those headers.

So far I've tried multiple consolidation techniques, but they either copy everything, or summarizing up all the numerical values.

When I tried to convert text in to header, it would allow for only one row to be converted, perhaps there is another way, but I could not find it.

'the code below copies the numbers if I will the table with numbers, but ignores strings

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sArray As Variant, i As Integer
ReDim sArray(1 To 1)

'---Make Array with Named Ranges to be Consolidated
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible And ws.Name <> "Consolidation" Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve sArray(1 To i)
        sArray(i) = ws.UsedRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, external:=True)
    End If
Next ws
If i = 0 Then Exit Sub

'---Consolidate using the Array
Sheets("Consolidation").Range("A1").Consolidate Sources:=(sArray), _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=False, LeftColumn:=False, CreateLinks:=False
```

Sheet1: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyfGs.jpg

Sheet2: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyfGs.jpg

Desired outcome: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMyVT.jpg

Once again, thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub CopyRows() 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
    ' Find the last row of data 
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    ' Loop through each row 
    For x = 2 To FinalRow 
        ' Decide if to copy based on column D 
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 4).Value 
        If ThisValue = "A" Then 
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy 
            Sheets("SheetA").Select 
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select 
            ActiveSheet.Paste 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
        ElseIf ThisValue = "B" Then 
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy 
            Sheets("SheetB").Select 
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select 
            ActiveSheet.Paste 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select 
        End If 
    Next x 
End Sub
```

This code helped to resolve the issue :-)